# Cannot hold constant RPM on Neutral with accelerator pedal

Tags: rpm, chrysler, emissions, town-and-country

Having Chrysler Town & Country 2008 with 4.0L gasoline engine.

Is it normal that i'm not able to keep engine at 2k RPM for 10 seconds? After some seconds, it just climbs itself up to 3k, but i'm not pushing pedal any stronger.

When driving, there is no issues - i can keep constant RPM. The engine, from my judgment, works well and I have no fluctuating or whatever.

I failed the CO2 emission tests at inspection, because the guy tried and tried and tried to keep constant RPM but couldn't.

Is the car being clever or there may be some issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: More.. could it be vscuum leak? RPM drops slowly after releasing acceleration pedal.